# JBOSS NoClassDefFoundError: org/ejbca/util/InterfaceCache

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, jboss5.x

I got the error `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to deploy the EJBCA API in my JSF project. When I deploy it in a simple java project, all goes fine with simple classes and JARs imported in the Java Build Path, but in the JSF that not happens.

I tried to copy the jars that I want from EJBCA folder and put in `MyProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` and nothing happened.

What must I do?

Comment: @Ted: when a suggested edit was so poor that you've to fix the edit altogether by *Improve* option, don't forget to uncheck the "Suggested edit was helpful" checkbox on save of the edit, otherwise you still reward 2 undeserved points to the edit suggester.